# Why is the list [1] not included in the answer P = [[]]? Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm learning Prolog but I came across this questions when learning about database manipulation.
when I ask the Prolog interpreter:

```
 findall(X,subset(X,[1]),P).
```

the only subset give is

```
P = [[]].
```

Why is this?

Comment: It's the built in predicate subset(SubSet,Set). Defined to be true is all elements of Subset belong to Set

Comment: swi prolog [https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subset/2](doc) warns that you should use sufficiently instantiated lists as inputs (the mode for `subset/2` is `+,+`)

Comment: Yes, this helped thank you! Both arguments have to be instantiated, but findall/3 worked because it always succeeds, giving the empty list [] as the output!

Answer (score 4):

In SWI-Prolog, the predicate `subset/2` is defined as:

```
% subset(+SubSet, +Set)

subset([], _) :- !.
subset([E|R], Set) :-
    memberchk(E, Set),
    subset(R, Set).
```

To obtain the desired result, you can use the following alternative definition:

```
% sub_set(?SubSet, +Set)

sub_set([], []).
sub_set(SubSet, [_|Set]) :- sub_set(SubSet, Set).
sub_set([X|SubSet], [X|Set]) :- sub_set(SubSet, Set).
```

Examples:

```
?- sub_set(S,[a,b,c]).
S = [] ;
S = [c] ;
S = [b] ;
S = [b, c] ;
S = [a] ;
S = [a, c] ;
S = [a, b] ;
S = [a, b, c] ;
false.

?- sub_set([a,c],[a,b,c]).
true ;
false.

?- findall(SubSet, sub_set(SubSet,[1]), PowerSet).
PowerSet = [[], [1]].
```